# Multiple buttons, each with different style - need to maintain hover state after clicked

Tags: javascript, button, hover, click

I have more than 3 buttons, each of them has a different style (different border color, different background color on hover).
(I created them with the `<li>` because they have an action to change the background-position of a picture).

I want them to maintain the same hover state appearance after they've been clicked, but to go back to the normal state when another button is clicked.

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance :)

*ps: I'm working in HTML with css, js when needed (like in this case).*

Comment: And what's your HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the complete lack of information about the HTML, and current JavaScript, you're using, the best I can offer is a simple demonstration of how this *might* be achieved:

```
function colorify (e) {
    // get a reference to the element we're changing/working on:
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo'),
        /* getting the siblings, the other controls,
           of the clicked-element (e.target):
        */
        controls = e.target.parentNode.children;
    // iterating over those controls
    for (var i = 0, len = controls.length; i < len; i++) {
        /* if the current control[i] is the clicked-element, we 'add' the 'active'
           class, otherwise we 'remove' it (using a ternary operator):
        */
        controls[i].classList[controls[i] == e.target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    }
    /* changing the background-color of the 'demo' element, setting it to the
       textContent of the clicked-element:
    */
    demo.style.backgroundColor = e.target.textContent;
}

var controls = document.getElementById('controls');

controls.addEventListener('click', colorify);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sQuPC/).

The above is based on the following HTML:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<ul id="controls">
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Green</li>
    <li>Blue</li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
#demo {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.active {
    color: #f00;
}
```

This approach requires a browser that implements the `classList` API, the `children` property of a DOM node, as well as the `addEventListener()` method of a Node.

References:

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children).